# Django separate thousands in template

Tags: django, django-templates

My model is returning a Decimal(1234567.50), I can't seem to display the Decimal with a thousands separator. Does Django have a way to do this? Do I need to create my own template filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [intcomma](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) filter.

Comment: I didn't know it worked on Decimal objects. Updated the answer.

Comment: Don't forget you need to `{% load humanize %}` to be able to use `intcomma`. Also you can combine this with `floatformat` to change how many decimal places are shown.

Comment: You can even combine `intcomma` wih `floatformat`, getting the benefit of both (`intcomma` for thousand separator, `floatformat` for minimal or no dot separator).

Comment: In order to use {% load humanize %} you have to activate it as INSTALLED_APPS, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/humanize/

Answer (score 7):

Add humanize to the installed apps in settings.py and load it in the template.

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ my_num|intcomma }}
```

Answer (score 4):

One easy way is to import `locale` and do the formatting in your view function.

Even easier to read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#overview

> For format localization, it’s just
>   necessary to set USE_L10N = True in
>   your settings file. If USE_L10N is set
>   to True, Django will display numbers
>   and dates in the format of the current
>   locale. That includes field
>   representation on templates, and
>   allowed input formats on the admin.

Comment: Django 1.2 now has a USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR variable you can set in settings.py. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#use-thousand-separator . This approach was much easier than using the intcomma filter. Once I set both USE_L10N and USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR to True, the numbers I wanted to show with thousands separators just started working auto-magically, no template editing necessary.

Update: this method seems to work with ints but not longs :(

Comment: What happen when `USE_L10N` doesn't work like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918523/django-localisation

Comment: USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR is evil because it converts other values. e.g. when using filebrowser, image.width will be formatted. When using thousands with dots, this will lead to width="1.200" height="800"... 1.2 instead of 1200

Comment: What is the solution for this ? How to use thousand operator only to specific number fileds?

Answer (score 3):

You could add the following to settings.py:

```
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```

That should work and you don't have to act with loading stuff.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#use-thousand-separator

Comment: Caution:  this setting can be evil - I broke a site by setting this to true because  values in templates with scripts, dynamic widths, etc. were being rendered with commas, which completely broke a pile of stuff.  Use with care!!

Comment: This doesn't work, my GET url parameters started showing with comas, breaking form functionalities.