# django thousand separator for product price in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, satchmo

i have the product price in decimals,

like 15000.0000

now i want to apply thousand separator on it, `intcomma` filter works fine with decimals [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270369/django-separate-thousands-in-template)

but after it i can't apply `currency` filter, means it didn't work with currency filter.

i want final output of my Price: PKR 15,000.00

any suggestions to get this?

Thanks :)

Comment: yes, i have set the local currency by using L10N_SETTINGS

Comment: Satchmo currency filter is using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The satchmo `currency` filter requires something that can be converted into a Decimal. However `intcomma` returns a string, and since it adds the thousand separators, it can no longer be converted to a Decimal.

The solution would be to write a `currency_with_intcomma` template filter yourself, which first runs through the `currency` filter and then applies the thousand separators (you can't use the builtin filter for that, you'll have to do it "manullay").