# Django localisation

Tags: django

I have set the following in my `settings.py` file:

```
USE_L10N = True
NUMBER_GROUPING = 3
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = '#'
USE_THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR =True
```

Yet my numbers are still printing out `12000.00`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

*(I'm on Django 1.3)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any locical reason why localisation won't work so ended up using the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909457/whats-the-easiest-way-to-add-commas-to-an-integer-in-python/3909495#3909495) on values before they are passed to a template

```
def commify(n):
    if n is None: return None
    n = str(n)
    if '.' in n:
        dollars, cents = n.split('.')
    else:
        dollars, cents = n, None

    r = []
    for i, c in enumerate(str(dollars)[::-1]):
        if i and (not (i % 3)):
            r.insert(0, ',')
        r.insert(0, c)
    out = ''.join(r)
    if cents:
        out += '.' + cents
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a helper template library that ships with Django (humanize) which has a filter called `intcomma` that sounds like it would do what you want.

Usage in a template:

```
{% load humanize %}
${{ value|intcomma }}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I am cycling through the variables dynamically, hence why I'm wondering why when I have set everything I  still don't get my int's seperated out