# sprate three digit with cama in django shopping project

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i have a html file that get my product model from database and show price of products.

i have a view:

```
def product(request):
    all_products = Product.objects.all()  
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'products':all_products})
```

and in html file i write:
{% for item in products %}

{{ item.price }}

{% endfor %}

i want for price for example: 1000000 $
output in html file show like this: 1,000,000 $

is there anyway to do this? i'm not familiar with java script... so please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True` in `settings.py`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73407763/18891495

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intcomma](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma) template filter to achieve that. Activate the filter by adding `django.contrib.humanize` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Then use `{% load humanize %}` in your html template.
You then add it to your variable like:

```
{{item.price|intcomma}}
```